# Organizing ssh aliases

Tags: bash, ssh

My `.ssh/config` is starting to grow with aliases, and remembering them all is getting harder.

Do you have any tips for better manage this growing collection?

For example an autocomplete when I type `ssh` of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

A rather crappy<sup>1</sup> completion for Bash:

```
function _ssh_complete () {
    local match=${COMP_WORDS[${COMP_CWORD}]}
    local hosts=
    local default=

    local _ssh_complete_hostlist=$( \
        grep "^\s*Host\s*=" ~/.ssh/config 2>/dev/null \
            | sed -r "s/^[^=]+= *//;s/ /\n/g" \
            | sort )

    for h in $_ssh_complete_hostlist; do
        if [[ $h =~ ^$match ]]; then
            hosts="$hosts $h"
        fi
    done
    if ! (( ${COMP_CWORD} == ${#COMP_WORDS[@]}-1 )); then
        default=$( compgen -f ${COMP_WORDS[${COMP_CWORD}]} )
    fi
    COMPREPLY=($hosts $default)
}
complete -F _ssh_complete ssh
```

You'll probably want to initialise `$_ssh_complete_hostlist` outside of the completion function (e.g. during shell init) otherwise you'll be spawning three programs per completion trial. The config file doesn't change that often that it would be necessary, and you can always call the initialisation function by hand when needed.

<sup>1)</sup> for example it only completes at the end of the line, so you have to state any options first and only then start typing and completing the remote host name.